# How to switch users using a script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash

I need to run a bash script in one profile as sudo, then when it's completed, I need to kill the bash script, log in to another profile, and then log out the profile the script started in.

How would this be done with Python or bash?

Comment: `then when its completed, I need to kill` Why do you want to kill something that's completed?

Comment: This sounds like an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The script was calling another script.  I was having trouble to get it to full end, without killing it.  I imagine this isn't the best way to do it.  But I need to be able to fully kill the script, ending all processes that the script might have been calling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo can execute commands as any user.

You can do:

```
sudo -u oneuser /var/lib/myscript
sudo -u anotheruser /var/lib/myscript
```

Also see [sudo man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Note that however runs the `sudo` must be root or have necessary permission mappings in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Is there a way to run those sudo commands using Python?

Comment: Running a sudo command is not different running any other shell command in Python.